# Best goodness-of-fit measure to determine: is my dataset power law or exponentially distributed?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, exponential-family, power-law

I would like to determine whether a discrete dataset that I'm modeling would be better fitted by an exponential function or a power law function.  I'm aware that a chi-squared test may be a suitable option to pursue.  However, I've heard that there are other, sometimes more sophisticated tests (e.g., K-S test, although that seems to be for continuous data), to determine the goodness-of-fit of a power law distributed or exponentially distributed dataset.  The question I'm facing is: Is my data distributed exponentially or is it distributed as a power law?  In other words, does an exponential model or a power law model describe my dataset better?  This goes directly into the issue of minimizing the SSE's for each type of model.

I would particularly appreciate it if rigorous mathematics formulas were provided in the answers to this question, as I'm keen on writing and implementing the program myself (i.e., I don't trust Microsoft Excel, and for good reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487582/r-squared-value-in-excel-with-the-addtrendline-function). If more details regarding my dataset are needed to answer this question, please comment below and I'll be happy to upload my full discrete dataset.

**Edit for clarification:** The distribution is Zipfian in nature (discrete), the y-values are proportions (all the y-values added up sum to 1).

Comment: when you say 'discrete' are these counts, or some other kind of discrete data? Usually "[exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)" is reserved for describing a distribution of continuous variables (the equivalent for a count-like variable is "[geometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)"). When you say "power law" for a discrete variable are you looking at a [Zipf distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law)? ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... You might find some of the information [Clauset, Shalizi and Newman](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062) useful, and also Shalizi's lighter and highly informative [post about it](http://vserver1.cscs.lsa.umich.edu/~crshalizi/weblog/491.html) (read both, they're full of good stuff). Are you interested in something more like comparing some diagnostic 'fit' criterion, or some kind of formal hypothesis test of fit, or perhaps a more Bayesian approach (start with prior probabilities on the two models, to try to derive some posterior probabilities given the data)?

Comment: Finally, have you considered that some other possibility than the two you mentioned may be more suitable?

Comment: @Glen_b The discrete data looks something like this: (1, 0.0723), (2, 0.0699), (3, 0.0645), etc. up to about x=100 and y=(some pretty small number), so each time as x goes up, y goes down.  Both a power law fit and exponential fit seem to model the data well, but the exponential looks much better (and I want to show that as rigorously as possible).  Those three alternatives you proposed all sound very interesting, I'd be very grateful if you could answer from all three perspectives as best you can and maybe weigh one against the others.

Comment: (i) What do the x-values represent (1,2,3 ...)? What are the y-values - do they represent sample proportions or something? How are they obtained?  (ii) "Both seem to fit the data well" sounds like you just tried two functions that occurred to you. Is there no subject-area theory to help guide the choice?  (iii) "Answer all three" sounds like a pretty unfocused question.

Comment: @Glen_b The distribution is Zipfian in nature (discrete), the y-values are proportions (all the y-values added up sum to 1).

Comment: generally, when one wants to compare power law vs. exponential - they mean rate of decay. Is this what you are looking for? In this current setup, it seems to me that this kind of question means nothing. Decay happens at the tail. If your distribution is supported on a bounded set, there is no tail.

Comment: @YairDaon The x-axis here is bounded (i.e., the last x-value is 100) and the values can be thought of as a bounded set of {(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...,(xn,yn)} where n is 100. And yes, this is a decay scenario (although some consecutive y-values are very close to others, especially towards higher n (the tails)).

Comment: @warship do you think of $x$ values becoming big and 100 is just the highest value you have? Because if not, as I mentioned, I **think** you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @YairDaon There is no confusion here, the question is pretty clear.